# SQL to select child rows only if all parents meet criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables Data and Parents. Basically what I want to do is make a search query that only selects a row from the Data table if all its parents have been tested (Tested = True). The following are examples of my tables:

```
Data
-------------------
ID         Version    Tested
A          1.1        True
B          1.2        True
C          0.2        False
D          0.6        False
```

-

```
Parents
-------------------
ChildID    ParentID
C          A
C          B
D          A
D          B
D          C
```

In this case C would only be returned in the query since it is the only one with parents that have all been tested:

```
Query
-------------------
ChildID    Version    Tested
C          0.2        False
```

Comment: Is this developed purely in MS Access eg form, subform, or are you working with other applications, because there are various different answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
select *
  from data d
 where not exists
 (select 1
          from parents p
         where p.childid = d.id
           and parentid in (select id from data where tested <> 'True'))
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bf20f/1/0

The only reason C is not the only one returned (A and B are also) is because A and B do not have any parents, do you want them to not be returned on that basis? (it is unknown whether all their parents have been tested because they have no parents)

If you do want them removed on that basis, use the following, and C will be the only returned:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bf20f/7/0

```
select *
  from data d
 where not exists
 (select 1
          from parents p
         where p.childid = d.id
           and parentid in (select id from data where tested <> 'True'))
   and id in (select childid from parents)
```